# Type Conversion Issue in PowerShell Script ( SSAS Tabular Context ) for SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, ssas-tabular, sql-agent-job

**Description:**

I am encountering an issue in my PowerShell script, which is intended to be executed as a SQL Server Agent job. The script involves manipulating Microsoft Analysis Services Tabular Model objects. The script works flawlessly when run in a PowerShell editor but fails when executed as a SQL Server Agent job.

**Problem:**

The specific issue revolves around type conversion errors when trying to set the data source for a partition. The error message is as follows:

> Cannot convert the "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource" value of type "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource" to type "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource".

**Code Snippet:**

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
Function  CreatePartition(  $partitonPrefix,   $partitonSuffix,  $query,  $datasource,   $reprocess)
{
    $spartition = $partitonPrefix + $partitonSuffix #concatinate to make partition name string
    Write-Output(" ")
    If ($mg.Partitions.Contains($spartition)) #check if partition exists
    {
        Write-Output("-------------------")
        Write-Output("Partition Exists: " + $spartition)
        if ($reprocess -eq "D")
        {
            Write-Output("Process Full on: " + $spartition)
            $date1 = Get-Date
            $partition = $mg.Partitions[$spartition]
 
            $partition.RequestRefresh([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType]::Full);
            # Save changes
            $db.Model.SaveChanges();
             $date2 = Get-Date
             Write-Output("Create Partition Completed: " + $spartition)
             Write-Output("Duration: " + ($date2 - $date1).ToString())
             Write-Output("-------------------")
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output("Nothing done")
        }
        Write-Output("-------------------")
    }
    else #create the partition
    {
        Write-Output("-------------------")
        Write-Output("Partition not found: " + $spartition)
        Write-Output("Creating partition: " + $spartition)
        $date1 = Get-Date
        $sourceQuery = $query
 
        # Retrieve the data source using the data source name
        #$dataSource = $db.Model.DataSources | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $datasourceName }
 

      # Create a new partition object for the specific table
        $partition = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Partition
        $partition.Name = $spartition
        $partition.Source = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.QueryPartitionSource
        $partition.Source.Query = $sourceQuery
        [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource]$partition.Source.DataSource = [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource]$db.Model.DataSources[$datasourceName]
        #$partition.Source.SetSource($dataSource)
 
        $partition.Mode = "Import"
 
        # Getting the partition info
        Write-Output("DataSource Type: " + $db.Model.DataSources[$datasourceName].GetType().FullName)
        Write-Output("DataSource Type: " + $partition.Source.DataSource.GetType().FullName)
      # Add the partition to the table's partitions collection
        $mg.Partitions.Add($partition)
 
      # Process the partition
      Write-Output("Process Full on: " + $spartition)
        $partition.RequestRefresh([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType]::Full);
      # Save changes
        $db.Model.SaveChanges()
 
 
        $date2 = Get-Date
        Write-Output("Create Partition Completed: " + $spartition)
        Write-Output("Duration: " + ($date2 - $date1).ToString())
        Write-Output("-------------------")
    }
}
```

**Context:**

The script is designed for daily processing of MSBI BI database using Analysis Services Tabular Model.
The script runs without errors in a PowerShell editor but encounters issues when executed as a SQL Server Agent job.

**Request for Assistance:**

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why this type conversion error is occurring specifically when the script is run as a SQL Server Agent job. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to resolve this issue are highly appreciated.

**Additional Information:**

SQL Server version: 19.1.56.0
PowerShell version: 5.1.17763.4974

Comment: What is `$db` and so, by extension, what is `$db.Model.DataSources`?

Comment: `$partition.Source.DataSource` is of type `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DataSource`, what happens if you remove all of the type coercion on that line?

Comment: Did you use following steps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/run-windows-powershell-steps-in-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver16#create-a-powershell-job-step

Comment: @AlwaysLearning db is the databases the ( Tabular Cube ) : '$db = $server.Databases.FindByNa me($ssasDatabaseName)'

Comment: When I remove the correction types, it gives me this error:  ` Cannot convert the "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource" value of type "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource" to type "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DataSource". `

Comment: @jdweng , yes the same

Comment: I'm guessing that if PowerShell runs and the scheduled version fails, it's because they are using different libraries. Check which ones are used in each context and get both on the correct version.